# Unexpected end of file error on valid code

Tags: php, yii

I'm getting the following error  for the function below on line 25 ie, `] );`

> syntax error, unexpected end of file

It's a yii application. The code seems valid. I checked the entire code in the file with some online validator and no issues were found. But it throws an error when run.

```
public function actionDashboard( $id, $recent_appointment_date = NULL )
        {
            $this->layout = 'doctor';
            $doc          = Doctors::find()->where( 'user_id=:id', [ ':id' => Yii::$app->session->get( 'user_id' ) ] )->one();
            $reminder     = new Remainder();
            if ( $recent_appointment_date != NULL )
            {
                $model = PatientBooking::find()->where( 'booking_date=:date', [ 'date' => $recent_appointment_date ] )->andWhere( 'doctor_id=:id', [ 'id' => $id ] )->orderBy( 'booking_time' )->all();
            }
            else
            {
                $model = PatientBooking::find()->where( 'booking_date=:date', [ 'date' => date( 'Y-m-d' ) ] )->andWhere( 'doctor_id=:id', [ 'id' => $id, ] )->orderBy( 'booking_time' )->all();
            }

            $booking  = new PatientBooking();
            $booking->doctor_id = $id;

            return $this->render( 'doc_view', [
                'model'    => $model,
                'id'       => $id,
                'doc'      => $doc,
                'booking'  => $booking,
                'reminder' => $reminder,

            ] );
        }
```

Comment: this code block seems fine, problem is somewhere in the whole code I think

Comment: or maybe your php version doesn't support `[]` for arrays, try old `array()` syntax

Comment: I checked the whole code with an online tool, and manually checked each line myself. No issues were found. Could this be an issue with some other files used in the project?

Comment: My php version is 5.5.22 and the short array support is there since 5.4 I think

Comment: yes you have to update php version to 5.4

Comment: Dude, I have 5.5. Do I need to go back to 5.4 now? @YatinMistry

Comment: No. If you have lower version below 5.4 then it need to update it.

Comment: Check for an empty line at the top of the controller class ( above the opening <?php )

Comment: I did. That's all fine. @eskimo

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your controller file. May be some where in your file code is not properly closed. Check your all functions and end of file curly braces.

Comment: I've checked the entire file with an online php code validator and no issues were found.

Comment: I have the same issue with some other functions in the same controller, and also in another controller too. All the errors occur at  $this->render lines.

Comment: what is your yii version? And place your one complete controller here.

Comment: Version is 2.0.3

Error message is as follows :

PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException

syntax error, unexpected end of file  in /var/www/html/drr/frontend/controllers/DoctorsController.php – yii\base\Controller::render() at line 571

Answer (score 0):

I think error "located" in **view file** (not in controller), such as error happens on line that rendered the view file.
For example may be you use tag `<?` instead of `<?php` in your rendered view file, but it not supported on your server.

Comment: The code of view file seems valid too. Couldn't find any issues. and my server supports shortcode too